# Colored text console output in Rebol

Tags: console-application, rebol, red

In some languages I can put [Esc codes](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) around text to make them colored on Linux console/terminal. However, this does not seem to work in Rebol:

```
NORMAL: "\e[0m"
RED: "\e[0;31m"

print rejoin["\e[0;31m" "red text" "\e[0m"]
```

Above code only produces black (usual colored) text output:

```
\e[0;31mred text\e[0m
```

Can colored text output be printed with Rebol on Linux terminal?

Comment: Assuming this is non-gui console on linux/unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can similarly use colour codes in Rebol/Red.

```
print "This text is ^[[0;31mred^[[0m text."
```

`#"^["` is the Escape character in Rebol/Red.

You can, for example, change the prompts in Red with the following codes:

```
system/console/prompt: "^[[31m^[[5D>>^[(B^[[m "
system/console/result: "^[[32m^[[5D==^[(B^[[m"
```

In the Ren-C branch of Rebol 3 you can change the prompts with the following (similar) codes:

```
system/console/prompt: "^[[31m^[[5D>>^[(B^[[m "
system/console/result: "^[[32m^[[5D==^[(B^[[m "
```

Comment: Where do I put text to be colored? Say, I want to print out "this is red text" with only "red" being colored red.

Answer (score 0):

```
   REBOL [
        Title:  "colorebol"
        Date:   14-Jul-2013
        File:   %colorebol.reb
        Version: 1.0.0
        Purpose: "Enable switching of terminal font colors and backgrounds etc"
        Note: "Includes the clr func for clearing the screen"
    ]

    clr: does [prin "^(page)"]

    coloreb: func [
    {Use Fore/Red /Green /Yellow /Blue /Magenta /Cyan /White /Reset and even /Black. Viola! Font-color
     Similarly Background/Blue etc...,  then Style/bright /dim /normal /reset_all and finally Cyclor, which
    randomly picks a font color. It needs some polishing}
    ][cyclor print ["this is all i do. that, and provide a help doc-string"] cyclor]

    Fore: make object! [

        Colors:   ["black" "red" "green" "yellow" "blue" "magenta" "cyan" "white" "reset"]
        BLACK:    does [prin "^[[30m"]
        RED:      does [prin "^[[31m"]
        GREEN:    does [prin "^[[32m"]
        YELLOW:   does [prin "^[[33m"]
        BLUE:     does [prin "^[[34m"]
        MAGENTA:  does [prin "^[[35m"]
        CYAN:     does [prin "^[[36m"]
        WHITE:    does [prin "^[[37m"]
        RESET:    does [prin "^[[39m"]
    ]

    Background: make object! [
        Colors:   ["black" "red" "green" "yellow" "blue" "magenta" "cyan" "white" "reset"]
        BLACK:    does [prin "^[[40m"]
        RED:      does [prin "^[[41m"]
        GREEN:    does [prin "^[[42m"]
        YELLOW:   does [prin "^[[43m"]
       BLUE:     does [prin "^[[44m"]
        MAGENTA:  does [prin "^[[45m"]
        CYAN:     does [prin "^[[46m"]
        WHITE:    does [prin "^[[47m"]
        RESET:    does [prin "^[[49m"]
    ]

    Style: make object! [
        Styles:    ["bright" "dim" "normal" "reset_all"]
        BRIGHT:    does [prin "^[[1m"]
        DIM:       does [prin "^[[2m"]
        NORMAL:    does [prin "^[[22m"]
        RESET_ALL: does [prin "^[[0m"]
    ]

    cyclor: func [] [fore/(to-word fore/colors/(random/only [2 3 4 5 6 7 8]))]
```

Put this in your other script files:

```
do %colorebol.reb
```

and then use it like so:

```
        col: has [
        "Wrap the colorebol.reb wrappers to reduce visual clutter"
         color /red /green /blue /yellow /cyan /magenta /black /white][
        if red [color: 'red]
        if green [color: 'green]
        if blue [color: 'blue]
        if yellow [color: 'yellow]
        if cyan [color: 'cyan]
        if magenta [color: 'magenta]
        if black [color: 'black]
        if white [color: 'white]

        if unixy-os? [fore/(color)]
    ]

    ;test it:
    col/magenta print "magenta" ;(it works). Maybe just mod /%colorebol.reb?
```

I'm not that fluent in Rebol - I'm sure there is a more concise way. But this has worked for me very well on GNU/Linux. To keep scripts portable I have an OS-detection function and the colorizing code is dependent on it.

Comment: The answer to your question is the very last line in code above.

Comment: Great script. You obviously liked my question.